# LDAP manipulation - Powershell or any other langage?

Tags: powershell, script, ldap

For a synchronization script, I need to connect to a LDAP (not an AD), search for few users then extract their usercertificate.

As the rest of the script is already written in PowerShell, I thought it would be great to do these steps with Powershell too.
Unfortunately, I can't find a proper module that would ease my tasks.

Thus, the question is going to be wide:
Do you know any PowerShell module that could help me achieving this OR what would be the best scripting langage to use for that?

Is is implied but my environment is Windows.

Thanks for your input

Answer (score 0):

Powershell probably still works best, but you would use the .net `[System.DirectoryServices]` class methods. If the LDAP server is similar enough to active directory, you can do a simple LDAP bind+query like this:

```
$path = "OU=SomeOU,DC=SomeDomain,DC=SomeTLD"
$filter = "(Name=SomeName)"
$ldap = [DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry]::New($path)
$Searcher = [DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher]::New($ldap,$filter)
$Searcher.FindAll()
```

Depending on your LDAP server, you may need to change the default SSL/authentication settings like the answer here for OpenLDAP: [Binding to a different active directory ldap instance in Powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26301835/7411885).